# Multiple copy from same file

Tags: c#, powershell

```
1..1000 | % { copy-Item "C:\path1\test1.xml" "C:\path2\test$_.xml"}
```

The above PowerShell code copies file from path1 and creates 1000 copies in path2.

How would I recreate this functionality in C# ?

Thanks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.copy?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_File_Copy_System_String_System_String_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
using System.IO;

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    File.Copy(@"C:\path1\test1.xml", $@"C:\path2\test{i}.xml");
}
```

Note: If the destination file exists, an IOException will be thrown. In that case, you can use the following overload that allows you to overwrite the file:

```
File.Copy(source, destination, overwrite: true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
 System.Linq.Enumerable.Range(1,1000).Select( i => 
     System.IO.File.Copy($"C:\\path1\\test1.xml", $"C:\\path2\\test{i}.xml");
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: NB: Typo in `Enumberable`, also `test$_.xml` should be `test{i}.xml`

Comment: Another typo - source file is always the same, check the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    System.IO.File.Copy("PathToCopyFrom", $"PathToCopyTo\\{System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("PathToCopyFrom")}_{i}{System.IO.Path.GetExtension("PathToCopyFrom")}");
}
```